# OnClickListener not called in Fragment

Tags: android, button, fragment, listener

private Button categories;

```
public Homefragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    categories=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.categories);
    categories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            categories.setText("Hello world!");
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
}
```

In the other fragments the event listener is working, but not in this one.
The button is correctly initialised, but the `onClick` method is not called, neither the onTouchlistener.
Help please.

Answer (score 1):

When you `inflate` the view it means Android will parse your xml to transform everything into View objects that you'll be able to use (to set a listener for example).

In you code you inflate your view, then set the listener (this part is correct) but after that you inflate an other view that you return.

It means everything you've done before `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);` is useless as you're not returning the view you set the listener on.

So remove:

`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);`

And instead do:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
     // Your code to set the listener
     //...

     // return the inflated view
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a new, not initialiazed view at the end of `onCreateView()`.

Change your code with :

```
public Homefragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    categories=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.categories);
    categories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            categories.setText("Hello world!");
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below code :

As you already used `View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);`, no need to return it. Return only reference.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    categories=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.categories);
    categories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            categories.setText("Hello world!");
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```